# Command line in Windows and Node.js

Tags: node.js, windows, command-line

I just installed node.js and try to execute my first "Hellow world" on it based on React.js
I moved step by step according to this article: https://www.kirupa.com/react/setting_up_react_environment.htm
All were fine untill I try to execute application through windows command line by command `./node_modules/.bin/webpack`. The result is error: **'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**
How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Windows uses `\` as the path separator. Just do `.\node_modules\.bin\webpack`

Comment: Or quote the command. Otherwise `cmd` will parse the first slash as the delimiter between the command name and its first argument, which ... doesn't go well.